# Using PHP to grab data from an XML feed when 2 or more fields have the same name

Tags: php, mysql, xml, simplexml, feed

I am having some issues getting this to work, I have a massive XML feed which I am putting into a MYSQL Database using PHP.

One XML article looks like this...

```
<Article Created="10:49:51" ID="800737873">
  <Heading>Week in review: Mobile, Google+ and Facebook grab headlines</Heading> 
  <Date>23/09/2011</Date> 
- <Contents>
- <![CDATA[ This week NewsReach has been busy at ad:tech, speaking to lots of people about how we can help websites with targeted online newsfeeds, landing pages and other copy.<br/><br/>But we still found time to keep our finger on the pulse of the wider digital world and bring those stories straight to our readers.<br/><br/>This week saw a big focus on mobile marketing, with several industry commentators highlighting the importance of the channel for online communications.<br/><br/>&lt;promo&gt;At NewsReach we can provide quality content for all online marketing platforms - call Jacey on 02075172240 to learn more.&lt;/promo&gt;Digital trainer <a href="http://www.newsreach.co.uk/nr/online-marketing/marketings-future-is-mobile">Rob Thurner noted</a> that mobile allows businesses to &quot;unlock new segments of consumers&quot;, while research by Head London highlighted the importance of good mobile websites.<br/><br/><a href="http://www.newsreach.co.uk/nr/online-marketing/mobile-websites-should-aid-integrated-experience">Report authors suggested</a> that mobile websites should not simply copy the desktop version's content and functionality, but should be designed in line with what mobile users want.<br/><br/>Mobile devices, in particular smartphones, are integral to young adults, according to a <a href="http://www.newsreach.co.uk/nr/online-marketing/internet-integral-to-young-consumers">study by Cisco</a>. The telecoms systems provider found under-30s regard it as vitally important to be able to access the internet on the go.<br/><br/>After about two months in limited field trial stage, <a href="http://www.newsreach.co.uk/nr/social-media-marketing/google-opens-doors-and-rolls-out-search">Google+ is now available to anyone</a> who wants to sign up. Google also rolled out a new search function, which will allow users to get personalised web search results within the social network.<br/><br/>And after much speculation, <a href="http://www.directnews.co.uk/news/facebook-overhauls-profiles-with-timeline-$21378257.htm">Facebook announced yesterday</a> that it will overhaul users' profile pages by introducing a virtual scrapbook that allows members to chronicle their life in one place. <br/><br/><em>Written by <a href="http://uk.linkedin.com/in/karenwebber">Karen Webber</a>, Deputy Head of News Feeds</em>
  ]]> 
  </Contents>
- <Summary>
- <![CDATA[ The future is mobile, while social networks continue their battle for supremacy. 
  ]]> 
  </Summary>
- <Picture Orientation="Landscape" PhotoTag="Mobile, Google+ and Facebook grab headlines" Ratio="1.00" PhotoID="7036189">
  <PhotoTag>Mobile, Google+ and Facebook grab headlines</PhotoTag> 
- <Large Width="500" Height="500">
  <URL>http://pictures.directnews.co.uk/liveimages/mobile+google+and+facebook+grab+headlines_3166_800737873_1_0_7036189_500.jpg</URL> 
  </Large>
- <Medium Width="300" Height="300">
  <URL>http://pictures.directnews.co.uk/liveimages/mobile+google+and+facebook+grab+headlines_3166_800737873_1_0_7036189_300.jpg</URL> 
  </Medium>
- <Small Width="100" Height="100">
  <URL>http://pictures.directnews.co.uk/liveimages/mobile+google+and+facebook+grab+headlines_3166_800737873_1_0_7036189_100.jpg</URL> 
  </Small>
  </Picture>
- <Categories>
  <Category ID="800089637">Online Marketing</Category> 
  <Category ID="800089646">ZHEADER</Category> 
  <Category ID="800092440">ZREVIEW</Category> 
  </Categories>
  </Article>
```

The part that I want to specifically talk about is this:

```
- <Categories>
  <Category ID="800089637">Online Marketing</Category> 
  <Category ID="800089646">ZHEADER</Category> 
  <Category ID="800092440">ZREVIEW</Category> 
  </Categories>
```

As you can see I have 3 Categories and 3 ID attributes. When getting the data using this method:

```
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('newsreacharchive2011.xml', null, true);

foreach($feed as $article) // loop through
{
   $category =  mysql_real_escape_string("{$article->Categories->Category}");
   $categoryID =  mysql_real_escape_string("{$article->Categories->Category['ID']}");
}
```

I only get the 1st of the 3 categories, so I am looking for some help getting hold of the next two categories, I dont know if I need to do a while loop within the foreach loop to get them or what, but im stuck so I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

------- EXTENSION -------

I have just tried this

```
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('newsreacharchive2011.xml', null, true);

    foreach($feed as $article) // loop through
    {
       $i = 0;
       while($i < 3)
       {
          $category[$i] =  mysql_real_escape_string("{$article->Categories->Category}");
          $categoryID[$i] =  mysql_real_escape_string("{$article->Categories->Category['ID']}");
           $i++;
       }
    }
```

and it still does not work

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($article->Categories);`? You probably need to loop around that variable to get each value.

Comment: `var_dump($article->Categories);` returns this `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { ["Category"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "SEO" [1]=> string(7) "ZHEADER" } } ` I have never seen `var_dump` before, how do I use it to help me solve this?

Comment: I will work with this to try and figure something out but this does not provide me with the ID attribute which i also need, thanks for your help Jon Stirling

Comment: You're right, that's where the attributes method of SimpleXML comes in handy. See [this](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$article->Categories->Category` is an array with entries for each `<Category>` element in the XML. In this case, there are three `Category` elements, so you need to iterate over each one.

```php
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement('newsreacharchive2011.xml', null, true);

foreach($feed as $article) // loop through
{
    foreach($article->Categories->Category as $category) {
        $categoryName = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$category);
        $categoryID = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$category['ID']);
        // add to database
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets me almost there, I used this code:
`foreach($article->Categories->Category as $category) 
{
    $category[] = (string)$category;
    $categoryID[] = (string)$category['ID'];
}`
and I got this result:
`Cat
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => 800089646 ) [0] => ZHEADER ) 
ID
Array ( [0] => 800089640 [1] => 800089646 ) `
which is almost what I want, im just getting an ID instead of Name in the Categorys array

Comment: Fixed it! My fault for having duplicate variable names! Thank you very much for this

Comment: @AdriftUniform: No problem. I'm glad I could help. I added `mysql_real_escape_string()` to better match your original sample code.